# How to create json file in a directory?

Tags: python, json

I got an error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'Users/bea/Desktop/iSight/Webservertesting/json/data1.json'
```

This is the code that I was running. Could you please help me fix this error.

```py
import json

def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt =  path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'r') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)
        fp.write(data)

writeToJSONFile("Users/bea/Desktop/iSight/Webservertesting/json", "data1", "book")
```

Comment: You have the wrong file open mode. If you want to write to the file (and create it) use mode='w': `open(filePathNameWExt, 'w')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te problem here is you need to change the 'r' to 'a' or 'w'

```py
def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt =  path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'a') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)
        fp.write(data)

writeToJSONFile("Users/bea/Desktop/iSight/Webservertesting/json", "data1", "book")
```

The reason for this is:

- 'r' opens a file thats there with read only.
- 'a' opens a file to append, however if it is not there it creates the file.
- 'w' opens a new file and writes too it, but if a file is there it overwrites the file